# How do I print the array of another class?

Tags: java, arrays

I have created an array with flight destinations in the public class flights and now I want to print out the array using a method in the public class customers. But for some reason the array always prints out as null and I sandly can't my mistake.

main class:

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        flight flight = new flight();
        customer customer = new customer();
        flight.createExampleData();
        customer.output();
    }
}
```

public class flights:

```java
public class flight{
    public String[] destination = new String[2000];
    public void createExampleData(){
        this.destination[1] = "Paris";
        this.destination[2] = "Geneve";
        this.destination[3] = "Florida";
    }
}
```

public class customers:

```java
public class customer{
    flight flight = new flight();
    public int i;
    public void output() {
        this.i=1;
        while (i<4){
            System.out.println("Flightnumber: " + this.i);
            System.out.println("Destination: " + flight.destination[this.i]);
            System.out.println("");
            this.i++;
        }
    }
}
```

(I can't put the print in the flights class for reasons not visible in this simplyfied version of the program)

Outcome from the method outpout after the method createExampleData:

---

Flightnumber: 1

Destination: null

Flightnumber: 2

Destination: null

Flightnumber: 3

Destination: null

---

Thanks for the help

Comment: You have `AnkuftOrt` and `destination`, which one is correct ? Note that array indexes start at 0.

Comment: And to answer your question, you get null since you never call `createExampleData()` in `output()`.

Comment: Voting to close as a typo

Comment: 1. Be sure to call `flight.createExampleData()`. 2. Use a `for` loop instead of a `while` loop here.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson the typo is only in the this post and not my code that doesn't work since I changed the names of the variables to english for the post. I call for the fuction in my main class which executes the function createExampleData() and then output(). but it still outputs null

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I call for createExampleData() in my main class which executes the function createExampleData() and then output(). Using a while loop instead of a for loop wouldn't change the problem with the null would it?

Comment: Then edit your code so that it is understandable using the correct variable name and include the `main()` method.

Comment: Please give a complete code example that we can copy and run ourselves. It should produce the exact output that you ask about.

Comment: And no, using a whole loop won't fix the problem. That was just a suggestion to improve your code. My apologies for not making that clear

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I did now. I hope it helps

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I fixed the mistakes and added the Main class. I hope it helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using two different `flight` objects, one created in `main` and one created in your `customer` class and then you call `flight.createExampleData` on the instance created in main but the `output` method uses the one in the `customer` object so the array in that one was never given any values, hence null in the output.

My suggestion for now is to make the `flight` variable in `customer` public

```
public class customer{
    public flight flight = new flight();
    ...
}
```

and then change main to

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        customer customer = new customer();
        customer.flight.createExampleData();
        customer.output();
    }
}
```

A better solution could be to add a getFlight() method to `customer` instead and keep the variable private.

Comment: Thanks a lot it works now. But could you briefly explain to me why I had to do it like that please?

Comment: @reichenwald Each instance of flight will have its own array `destination` and since your `output()` method belongs to the customer object it uses the `flight` object that also belongs (is a member variable) to customer. So therefore you need to call createExampleData() on the right instance of `flight` so that the right `destination` array gets updated.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you haven't executed the function `createExampleData()` in your `customers` class?

Comment: I have in my main class which executes the function createExampleData() and then output()

Comment: @reichenwald, i think you should check the answer by Joakim Danielson, i agree with him. Also i hesitate about the line  `flight flight = flight flight();` in customers class, maybe it's better to use `flight flight = new flight();`. Finally, names of the classes traditionally start with upper-case letter. (they become more recognizable). For example, Customer or Flight.

Answer (score 0):

```
    flight.createExampleData();
```

When you call this, createExampleData method in Flight class is executed.

```
    customer.output();
```

When you call this output method in Customer class is executed.

There is no relationship between Flight and Customer class in your code. So, customer object's output method wouldn't know what happened in the createExampleData of Flight class.

You can rather do this

```
  String [] flightDestinations = flight.createExampleData();
  customer.output(flightDestinations);
```

You will have to change your output method in customer class to use this string array and print its details. Also, the return type for createExampleData should be String [] for this to work.